# Is there anyway to get the EV battery details from the car?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-auto, android-automotive

I need to show the remaining battery of the EV inside my mobile app. Is there any possible way to get this information from the car. I went through this documentation [CarPropertyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager) they have mentioned some details but I am not able to implement CarPropertyManager.CarPropertyEventCallback this callback as CarPropertyManager is not found

Comment: `CarPropertyManager` appears to be part of Android Automotive, which is a version of Android that runs on the car, not on a phone. "Is there any possible way to get this information from the car" -- that probably varies by vehicle model.

Comment: But I need to show that inside the app.. Not inside car head unit. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "But I need to show that inside the app" -- then talk to the manufacturer of the car.